# Повесить на кого-то собак

Tags: значение-слов, этимология

Откуда пошло это выражение и что оно значит? Когда его уместно применять?

Answer (score 3):

Обычная форма для этого фразеологизма: "повесить *всех* собак". Без "всех" не очень точно передаёт смысл.

Со значением тут все понятно. Обвинить человека во всех грехах и бедах или ошибках, часто - ложно, огульно оговаривать.

А что касается происхождения, то не могу сейчас ссылку дать: некогда искать да проверять, но своими словами скажу.

К домашним "друзьям человека" прямого отношения не имеет. Дело в том, что у слова ***"собака"*** есть еще одно, переносное, значение - ***репей, соцветие репейника (лопуха большого)***. Можете представить, что происходит с субъектом, решившимся прогуляться по зарослям репейника в период созревания семян?! Он весь будет увешанным в "собаках". Отсюда же *вцепился как собака*.

*На всякий случай. Эта версия когда-то давно была где-то озвучена, мной прочитана - и сначала вызвала внутренний протест, ибо я, как и большинство современных людей, не был знаком с таким значением. Но потом, обнаружив значение в каком-то древнем словаре, свыкся с мыслью, что она правильна. Может и найдёте. Других комментариев сейчас дать не могу.*

Answer (score 0):

Чуть подробнее. По словам культуролога Анастасии Мелехиной собаками в просторечии называют репейник.

До сих пор, приехав в какую-нибудь дальнюю глухомань, можно услышать от пожилого человека: "Ого, сколько собак на себя нацепляла".

В далекие языческие времена, во времена суеверий наши предки считали репейник отличным средством для наведения порчи на врагов.

Собаке, то есть репейнику рассказывали все, что думали о неприятеле. Желали тому всяческих неприятностей. Затем цепляли колючки к платью противника. В общем вешали собак — наводили тем самым порчу. Прямое значение фразы стерлась в веках. Но осадочек — остался.

В словаре Ушакова фразеологический оборот - "вешать собак" приведен под словом собака. Но в нем не указано значение слова собака. Судя по контексту, составитель статьи о собаке связывал это определение с просторечно-бранным значением слова собака, то есть, негодяй, презренный человек.

Однако, по словарю В. И. Даля, у слова "собака" другое значение, так называется колючка, репейник, репей.